# Can I create an alternative method name in Java , so it can be called by either the self-defined name, or the required method name?

Tags: java, methods, alias

I am required to use the method name setNumberMeAndTheRest() in my Java assignment.
Is it possible to define a shorter and more apt name as well as allow the method to be called by the required name?

Comment: Yes, you can.  That doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Much of the experience with Java is learning to use existing conventions and naming.  This is what makes your programs readable to others.

Comment: Sounds like yet another assignment given by a college professor who has never had a real job developing software.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can define a wrapper method.

For example:

```
   class MyClass {
      void setNumberMeAndTheRest( ) { ... }
      void setWithShorterName() { setNumberMeAndTheRest(); }
      ...
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public void m(Object arg1) {
   ridiculouslyLongNamedMethod(arg1);
}
```

You might also want to check out if your editor and/or IDE can help you, via code-completion, abbreviations etc.

Or write your assignment using the short name, and do a quick refactor prior to submission. You should be able to confirm that your refactor worked via compilation (in the simple case) and/or unit tests (more properly).

Comment: This is how I would do it, personally.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another method with a shorter name and call the long-named method from it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes. Several of the answers show how to do this. However, stylistically, there is much to be said for the clarity provided by long (enough) method and variable names. The time and effort you'll "waste" typing them out will likely be made up in the time it takes to remember what you meant in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
void myfunction(args)
{

setNumberMeAndTheRest(args);

}
```

call myfunction() and it will in turn call your function, simple!!!